# Metadata file 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' could not be opened -- 'Error importing module 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

OS: Windows 8.1

Visual Studio Premium 2013

I have a complex MVC application that I have been running for years. I am able to run the application in debug without issues. However, just this afternoon, when I tried to publish the application for deployment I receive this error:

> Error 8   Metadata file 'f:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\GIT\Maloha\site\bin\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' could not be opened -- 'Error importing module 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' of assembly 'f:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\GIT\Maloha\site\bin\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' -- The system cannot find the file specified. '    F:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\GIT\Maloha\site\CSC site

I have restarted my computer.
I have tried to clean and rebuild the application.

What would cause this to suddenly appear? How do I fix it? I need to be able to publish the application.

**UPDATE**

I uninstalled .NET 3.5 and reinstalled it. I can now see the file in the specified folder, but I still get the error.

Comment: Have you tried installing `.NET 4.5` and see if you still have that issue?

Comment: It is Windows 8.1 so .NET 4.5 is already installed.

Comment: I figured. This must be a typo then.`I uninstalled .NET 3.5 `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I have no idea if my solution will work for you, but here is what someone told me to do:

Delete the files from the bin folder so they can be rebuilt with the next publication.

I have no idea why it worked, but I was able to use the solution after that.

Unfortunately, I can't provide any additional insights or directions beyond this.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the project or delete the files from bin folder and then rebuild it again, it happened with me twice and that was the solution which solved my problem